# Powershell Create User Inbox and Set User Details

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that creates a user inbox and fills in AD details. I've gotten it to create the users inbox but when i try to use Set-ADUser I get an error because it cannot find the user. How can I set the AD details when I'm creating the mailbox?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
New-Mailbox -Name "$First $Last" -Alias "$First.$Last" 
-OrganizationalUnit "j2global.com/Employees/$Location/$Department" 
-UserPrincipalName "$First.$Last@j2global.com" 
-SamAccountName "$First.$Last" -FirstName "$First" 
-LastName "$Last" -Database "$Database" -Password $SecurePassword 
-ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $False 

Set-ADUser "$First.$Last" -Department $Department 
-Description $Description -Manager $Manager 
-StreetAddress $StreetAddress -City $City 
-State $State -Country $Country -Title $Title 
-HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory
```

Comment: does `Get-ADUser "first.last"` work manually for the failing account?

Comment: Was trying to see if there was a passthru but does not look like if for `new-mailbox`. Could just be a matter of time and you could cheat with a `sleep`. Is the account actually created? Perhaps you have a replication interval you need to wait for? You could also do this backwards. Create the account with all the attributes and then `Enable-Mailbox`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to do it too quickly and exchange hasnt replicated the change with AD and all your domain controllers here is what I would do:

add: `sleep 10` between the `new-mailbox` and `set-aduser`

When creating a new account changes are replicated instantly but they aren't that instant. Most other changes are replicated between domain controllers every 15 minutes.

```
New-Mailbox -Name "$First $Last" -Alias "$First.$Last" 
-OrganizationalUnit "j2global.com/Employees/$Location/$Department" 
-UserPrincipalName "$First.$Last@j2global.com" 
-SamAccountName "$First.$Last" -FirstName "$First" 
-LastName "$Last" -Database "$Database" -Password $SecurePassword 
-ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $False 

# Wait for 10 seconds for AD to replicate with exchange
sleep 10

Set-ADUser "$First.$Last" -Department $Department 
-Description $Description -Manager $Manager 
-StreetAddress $StreetAddress -City $City 
-State $State -Country $Country -Title $Title 
-HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory
```